# angular2-csv how to add headers bold?

Tags: angular, export-to-csv

this.personList have some array of elements. I want to add the header row Firstname, Lastname and Email is to bold.
I have used Angular2Csv module for downloading csv

```
import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv';

downloadCSV() {
            let options = {
                fieldSeparator: ',',
                quoteStrings: '"',
                decimalseparator: '.',
                showLabels: true,
                showTitle: true,
                useBom: true,
                headers: ['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']
            };

            new Angular2Csv(this.personList, 'Person List', options);
        }
```